# QML Map Debugging

Tags: qt, qml

I have made some small modifications to the [minimal_map](https://github.com/qt/qtlocation/tree/5.11/examples/location/minimal_map) demo to allow it to use offline tiles. It works perfectly on my desktop, but when I run it on my embedded target, it only loads a blank gray screen. I assume that I am probably missing a required component on the embedded target. It has the QLocaiton module as well as the OSM plugin. The only error message that I get is `qrc:/main.qml:87:24: Unable to assign [undefined] to QDeclarativeGeoMapType*` from this line `activeMapType: supportedMapTypes[supportedMapTypes.length - 1]`. This is because on the embedded target, `supportedMapTypes.length` returns 0. Can someone recommend some ideas on how to debug this. It is difficult with only this error message.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtLocation 5.6
import QtPositioning 5.6

Window {
    width: 800
    height: 480
    visible: true

    Plugin {
        id: mapPlugin
        name: "osm"

        PluginParameter {
            name: "osm.mapping.custom.host"
            value: "file:///usr/bin/resources/maptiles/"
        }
        PluginParameter {
            name: "osm.mapping.providersrepository.disabled"
            value: true
        }
        PluginParameter {
            name: "osm.mapping.cache.directory"
            value: "/home/asdf/Documents/cache"
        }

        Component.onCompleted: {
            console.log("Plugin loaded")
        }
    }

    Map {
        anchors.fill: parent
        plugin: mapPlugin
        zoomLevel: 7
        activeMapType: supportedMapTypes[supportedMapTypes.length - 1]

        Component.onCompleted: {
            for( var i = 0; i < supportedMapTypes.length; i++) {
                console.log(supportedMapTypes[i].name)
            }

            console.log("Map loaded")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Qt do you have? What is your OS ?, I tested it on Linux with Qt 5.11 and I have not had any problems.

Comment: @eyllanesc I am running it on Ubuntu 18 and Raspberrian and they both work fine. It's only when I run them on my own custom linux build that it gives this error. I figure that I probably missed an option when compiling Qt.

Comment: Do not you think it would be right for you to indicate this in your question?

Comment: I would be very interested by more info on this. I have a similar issue where  my Plugin works on a Debian but not on Ubuntu, where the supportedMapTypes array is empty.

Comment: @FrançoisLegras That's good to know. It should be easy to write a bug ticket on the Qt site since you can reproduce it on a desktop platform.